# Vim - mapping different commands to keys and CTRL sequences

Tags: vim

In [Practical Vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim2/practical-vim-second-edition) there is a word of caution about how `<C-I>` and `<Tab>` are actually functionally identical and mapping one affects the other.  The [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)) has a similar note of caution for the following table:

```
Ctrl-I      Tab
Ctrl-[      Esc
Ctrl-M      Enter
Ctrl-H      Backspace
```

Not knowing this, I set up `<Ctrl-H>` to move a window to the left (calls `TmuxNavigateLeft` from [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator)) and mapped `<BS>` to `:b#` to quickly switch to the alternate buffer.  Both seem to work fine, with no apparent conflict.  When does the conflict arise, under what circumstances should I be concerned, and why are my current mappings working?

My vimrc mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <BS> :b#<CR>
```

[Relevant line in vim-tmux-navigator plugin](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator/blob/master/plugin/tmux_navigator.vim#L123):

```
nnoremap <silent> <c-h> :TmuxNavigateLeft<cr>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are confused by this line `Ctrl-H      Backspace` ? If so, you need to read it like this **from left to right**: "the combinations of keys `Ctrl-H` **behaves like** the default Backspace which is in other words removing a character or going left." It does not interfere with the **key** `<bs>`.

Comment: Could you share your mappings as well? Like what you added to achieve your mappings

Comment: Updated with mappings.